# Pub/sub with durable messages with Rebus

Tags: servicebus, rebus

I need a way to publish messages to unknown number of subscribers. The messages should be durable/persisted and categorized into three priorities (high, medium and low). One of the subscribers can only handle a limited load and some messages are just more important. High-prioritized messages processed first etc.

How do I do that with Rebus? I guess I need three queues per subscriber?

Where can I find a publish/subscribe example with durable queues and MSMQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some info: Rebus likes to work with durable queues, durable messaging, and guaranteed delivery. In fact, unless you actively do stuff to opt out, that's the way everything works. So if you manage to make pub/sub work with Rebus, it's durable :)

Publishing by definition works with an "unknown number of subscribers" - at least that's a bus concern, and not an application concern.

In reality, subscribers initiate pub/sub conversation by issuing a `SubscriptionMessage` (which can be seen as a subscription request), which is then followed by the publisher publishing some number of events (which can be seen as "subscription replies"). The "bus part" of the publisher keeps track of who subscribed to any given event type.

So far, so good.

Regarding priorities, there's no out-of-the-box way to achieve that with Rebus. One way to ensure a maximum latency on certain message types is, as you're suggesting, by making separate endpoints whose input queues will not be clogged by low priority messages.

But there is some stuff around how Rebus is configured that strongly suggests having only one single input queue in each process, so that would probably imply that you should create separate processes that subscribe to those high priority message types.

I know that MSMQ supports some kind of priority on messages, so I guess it *could* be supported by having `MsmqMessageQueue` understand certain headers (similar to how express delivery and time-to-be-received are implemented - see [here](https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Transports/Msmq/RebusTransportMessageFormatter.cs#L63)) - pull requests are happily accepted and strongly encouraged :)

Comment: Do I need to configure an endpoint for each subscriber? Where is the messages to the subscribers stored? Have not been able to find a sample implementation.
I will look into the MSMQ message prioritization.

Comment: Messages to the subscribers are stored in each subscriber's input queue. The publisher sends a copy directly(*) to each individual subscriber when publishing.

Comment: *) And by "directly", I means with MSMQ store-and-forward, so it is completely safe :)

Comment: Do you have a example I can take a look at?

Comment: well yes, in fact there's a pub/sub sample in the samples solution: https://github.com/mookid8000/Rebus/tree/master/samples/Rebus.Samples

Comment: (at least now, there is ;))

Comment: I the sample a Saga is used. Are Saga's required for pub/sub?

Comment: In the pub/sub sample, there's no saga - and no, sagas are just a shortcut to having incoming messages correlated with a piece of state.

Comment: Ohh - transitional message and message priority does not go hand in hand. MSMQ guarantee message delivery order within a transaction, therefor message submitted with a transaction is delivered in that order, no matter the priority. All transactional message has the priority of zero (low priority). [See here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msmq/thread/92d2ea87-594c-4f9c-8286-35bf21518002)

Comment: Bummer! so that's probably why I have never heard about anyone actually using that feature - it's practically useless